# Namespaces for EF POCO Classes

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Is there any advantage in creating  a separated namespace for each of my POCO classes in a Code First Entity Framework project ?

this:

```
namespace Domain.POCO.Table1
{
    class Table1 { }
}

namespace Domain.POCO.Table2
{
    class Table2 { }
}
```

instead of this:

```
namespace Domain.POCO
{
   class Table1 { }
}

namespace Domain.POCO
{
    class Table2 { }
}
```

in the first case one can say the code is "better organized" but this option creates a lot of "using" statements everywhere else on the code.

Is there any benefit related to assembly loading or other  ?

Comment: Why would you want to use `Domain.POCO.Table1.Table1`? Also, those are generally called *entities* not POCOs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any advantage in creating a separated namespace for each of my POCO classes

No, and there *is* a [general guideline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/names-of-namespaces) against naming a class and a namespace the same. In contrast to the filename, that should be equal to the class name.

So I would suggest

```
// MyEntity1.cs
namespace MyProject.Domain.Entities
{
   public class MyEntity1 { }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no advantage to having one-class-per-namespace. You can group related objects in the same namespace if it makes sense to you, but having a namespace for each class is just going to make the code more verbose for now reason.